# Form valdiation email using button with link

Tags: html, forms, validation, email

I am trying to do something very simple using html, however I don't find an easy way to solve this, without onclick javascript events.

My code is like this:

```
           <div class="email">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <a href="validation.html">
                    <button class="subscription-button">Keep Me Posted!</button>
            </a>
```

This is fairly simple.

Without the `href="validation.html` tag, I get an automated form validation,
notifying when '@' is missing and such.
**However, when adding the link to the page, this validation is not checked, and it goes on to the next page.**
How can I make it check the constraints without needing to write JS for that?

I tried this:

```
          <form action=./validation.html>
            <div class="email">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Keep Me Posted!" />
            </form>
```

But the same result

Comment: A button is not a valid element inside of a link. Use a [`<form>` with an `action=` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Comment: I tried that too, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the form instead of link with a `required` attribute prevent empty data to auto validate the email type

```html
<form action="validation.html">
      <div class="email">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit"  class="subscription-button">Keep Me Posted!</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This sworks. Hmmm... Not sure why my other solution didn't work!

Comment: You missed a `required` attribute in the form field. Please mark as accepted answer if it helped you.

Comment: I am trying, I have to wait 6 minutes

Comment: No worries. Happy that i could be of some help

Answer (score 1):

I removed the slash from next to validation.html.

**Try this:**

```
<form action="validation.html">
  <div class="email">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit"  class="subscription-button">Keep Me Posted!</button>
</form>
```